# Как получить ссылку на выставленный пост в telegram?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Одним кубиком в "Node.JS" сделал вот что:
Написал на Nodejs 18 (npm пакеты node-telegram-bot-api и fs-extra) отправку поста с картинкой через телеграм-бота в мой публичный телеграм-канал.
Пост ставится отлично!
Причём в коде сделал чтоб после публикации получить ссылку (линк) на выставленный пост. Но ссылку не получаю в переменой url. Где косяк не пойму.

Код:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const bot = new TelegramBot('653***ТОКЕНБОТАСКРЫЛ****_JQ');

const text = 'текст поста';

const photo = fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\kartinka_preview.jpg');

bot.sendPhoto('@ТУТЮЗЕРНЕЙМКАНАЛА', photo, {caption: text, parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
  .then(message => {
    const channelId = 'ТУТЮЗЕРНЕЙМКАНАЛА'; 
    const messageId = message.message_id;
    const url = `https://t.me/${channelId}/${messageId}`;
console.log('URL of the posted message:', url);

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
  });
```

Comment: Ну что то вы там должны получать. Что сечас ваша консоль выводит?

Comment: спасибо всем! уже сам разобрался

Comment: закройте вопрос